# Given a query string and the empty form html it came from generate filled in html

Tags: perl, post, get, query-string, forms

I have an html with empty forms and I have the query string that was generated when filling in those forms.

How can I merge them together into a filled in html page?

Hopefully you can give me a perl based solution.

**Edit:** I have a web **scraper** based on WWW::Mechanize with perl. I am saving the html content to generate a hmtl slideshow of the session, however I can't save the html with the filled-in values.

I have looked at mechanize source and the it is creating a HTML::Form object to handle the forms. I have looked at HTML::Form and I don't see how I can turn the object back to html, there is just a dump method.

There is a section in HTML::Form code that lets me generate the POST or GET request and I thought that maybe that was a good starting point to generate filled-in hmtl by merging the request with the original html.

```
if ($method eq "GET") {
    require HTTP::Request;
    $uri = URI->new($uri, "http");
    $uri->query_form(@form);
    return HTTP::Request->new(GET => $uri);
}
elsif ($method eq "POST") {
    require HTTP::Request::Common;
    return HTTP::Request::Common::POST($uri, \@form,
        Content_Type => $enctype);
}
```

So I can use that code snipet in my mechanize program after I am done filling forms to get the final POST or GET request but that is as far as I go :(

Comment: Do you want to write HTML or use a web scraper to submit the form?

Comment: All your questions go in this direction. What is it you actually want to do? Please try to explain the bigger picture!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to show the form with its values.

All you have to do is set the value of a form element to be the value from the query string.

if you give more info, we can tell you more specific answers...

Comment: I am not an html expert so I don't know if I can just match the filled-in field (or checked box, or selected radio) from my GET or POST request and match it with the first occurrence of that in the html source to change the value of that item. I can roughly think of how to do it using HTML::Treebuilder but I don't know if that is the smart way to go and if that will cover all (or at least most) cases.